# Should a question's title be related to a common problem or a personal problem?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I am seeing questions which look like they want their work to get done from others.

**For Example**

[Can I do without this cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606779/can-i-do-without-this-cursor)

Such questions asked on StackOverflow will not be helpful for users who search for a similar problem. I think the title should be related to the problem for any question asked, and that it should be reviewed before posting.

The title to any question should be helpful for others, to find and solve their question.

Comment: I mostly understand your complaint, but not your requested feature. What do you mean by `Problem Related Title to " Any Question asked"` and `that to get "reviewed" before "posting"`? (The quotation marks and bold are confusing me). Do you mean that all questions should have their titles reviewed before going up on the site? (That would be a *massive* reviewing ordeal...)

Comment: Yes! I think all Questions Asked should have title review. I know its very huge number, but if there is a provision in flag that `Title Review Needed` then it will be better.

Comment: A "personnel" problem sounds more like a matter for HR.

Comment: A Question asked can help other if and only if Title of that Question is having proper **Title**.

Comment: @Makoto: We've actually had people mistake "Title" for "Job Title" rather than "Question Title" when posting their questions.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn:  So I've been trying for the last two minutes to comprehend how that's possible, but...I'm honestly at a loss for words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever I've seen these sorts of titles, I've done one of two things:

- If the question is reasonable, save for the title, I would edit the title to better fit the question scope.
- If the question is blatantly asking for a solution, opinion, "gimmie teh x", or any variant thereof, I would vote to close without much of a second thought.

It's one of those things that's overlooked when doing reviews/edits - the title of the question counts just as much as the actual body of the question.

Now, as for a *title* review - given that there are some people only reviewing for the badge, the very thought of explicitly adding this makes me very, *very* sad.  In all actuality, it **should** be one of those things checked during a normal review.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with questions is that if you are asking a "correct" question - (using the right terms, etc.) you already have at least 50% of the solution. In many cases the question is not correct from the very beginning and the subject of the question becomes more clear during the discussion either using comments or partial answers. So I don't think that "title review" will help here.

Even more - as there are a lot more people in the Internet than in the StackOverflow community, even the strangest question may "attract" people from the outside that think the same incorrect (in professional terms) way.

I will give as an example a recent joke I have heard:
The girl asks her friend: "I've opened the movie, but it was in Russian. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but it was still in Russian".

The question here shows completely incorrect understanding how the language is switched in movies and in keyboard input. But I bet that there are more than one person in the world that would face the same problem and ask the same question. And Google will find that question either by title or its body or (for ones that know how to ask using the right terms) by answer itself.

Of course, if the title is completely irrelevant to the question it should be reviewed as a part of question review, but not as a separate review queue.

Comment: This way it will solve the problem of person who asked, but what about who is Googling for same problem, how he will come to know that there is similar question asked and solution also present.

Comment: @RJ1990 See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think bad titles attract attention because they stand out in the Newest waterfall.  So the community is swift to action, either editing the titles to something more meaningful quite quickly, or more likely down-voting the questions and/or voting to close.

I think this is a situation where the existing SO mechanics work well enough.  So there really isn't any need to introduce a new feature, particularly when most titles are sufficiently accurate and informative.